# Internet email is being routed to origin (@) IP address instead of address specified in MX and A record

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

We have setup a mail server and created the following DNS records. Assuming our domain is example.com:

```
A    @              10.0.0.5
A    mail           10.0.0.1
MX   example.com    mail.example.com
```

Note `10.0.0.1` is just an example. We are actually using a public IP address instead.

We have also had our hosting company setup a proper PTR record pointing to `mail.example.com` and `10.0.0.1`.

For some reason, when people send up email, they don't deliver and have this message on the return mail message:

> The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7720 [example.com 10.0.0.5: timed out]

For some reason, instead of trying to connect to `10.0.0.1` email servers on the web are trying to connect to `10.0.0.5`, our `origin` (`@`) address.

We don't want to point `@` to our mail server if we can help is as we have a ton of `CNAME` records pointing to `@` for web hosting purposes.

Have we incorrectly setup our DNS? What can we fix it?

Comment: Is the correct `10.0.0.1` IP address returned when you run `nslookup mail.example.com`? How long ago did you change these DNS records - remember that DNS changes can take up to 24 (sometimes 48) hours to fully propagate - whatsmydns.net should help with this.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the record over at GoDaddy for `mail` is an `A` record? These records only accept IP addresses, so the value of `mail.example.com` for your `A` record cannot be valid.

Comment: @brendonofficial thank you for the comments. Yes, `nslookup mail.example.com` returned correct IP address, but MX record was not being found. I fixed the errors in my question.

Answer (score 4):

Can you post the real domain and records? My immediate guess is that your MX record should just read `mail`.

Because you have `mail.example.com` without a `.` on the end, it is resolving to `mail.example.com.example.com` - I don't know why that would be resolving to your `10.` address, but without seeing the real zone with the real entries we can't really tell.

Comment: Perhaps if it doesn't find the MX it will fall back to the address directly: example.com's IP.

Answer (score 4):

This is confusing:

```
A    @     10.0.0.5
A    mail  10.0.0.1
MX   10    mail.example.com
```

To me this reads as:

```
@      A    10.0.0.5
mail   A    10.0.0.1
       MX   10  mail.example.com
```

So you're creating an MX record for `mail.example.com` and not for `example.com`.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. This helped me indentify the problem, which was an incorrectly setup MX record.

Comment: @SwisherSweet : can you mark my answer then as the solution?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I had my MX record setup incorrectly.

I changed from this (GoDaddy fields):

```
Type      Host          Points to         Priority    TTL
MX        example.com   mail.example.com  10          1h
```

To this:

```
Type      Host          Points to         Priority    TTL
MX        @             mail.example.com  10          1h
```

Mail is now coming in and I am finding my MX record using MXToolbox.com.

Comment: Perhaps the host field had to contain the value `example.com.` instead. These web interfaces can be really annoying sometimes. In the "points to" field no trailing dot is required, but in the host field it is (this is my guess at least).